# HttpClient устарел? Что можно использовать вместо него?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpclient

Прошу строго не судить) в программировании относительно недавно. Нужно отправить на сервер запрос с token в header'е. Посмотрела в интернете, но там все устаревшее(HttpClient, HttpPost). Подскажите, пожалуйста какие инструменты использовать и как этот инструмент будет взаимодействовать с AsyncTask. Если несложно примеры тоже скиньте). Спасибо.

Comment: HttpURLConnection

Comment: а как к HttpURLConnection добавлять header?

Comment: Методом [setRequestProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Я бы советовал okhttp библиотеку посмотреть, она мощнее чем просто urlconnection.

Comment: а как вернуть token?

Comment: как сделать авторизацию ? нужно отправить логин и пароль, если они верные, то взамен получить токен.

Comment: @pavel а я бы советовал новичку сначала поработать со стандартными решениями, чтобы понимать, как оно под капотом, а потом уже сторонние библиотеки использовать

Comment: @qwerty ну как простой вариант: отправляете одним запросом логин и хэш пароля, в ответ получаете от сервера токен (и лучше еще один renew_token), который использовать для восстановления сессии, когда стандартный токен устарет. Далее с каждым запросом шлете token, а сервер проверяет можно ли Вам делать этот запрос, да и вообще кто из клиентов его делает. Это если очень кратко и примитивно.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov можете образец скинуть?

Comment: Что значит образец? Готовый код сервера и клиента? Такого Вам никто не скинет. Пытайтесь по описанному алгоритму реализовать все по этапам.